# Failure to start ufw after OpenVPN connection

Tags: vpn, openvpn, ufw

I have currently configured my Ubuntu system to connect to an OpenVPN server on startup. This is done by placing a configuration file in the `/etc/openvpn` directory.

Additionally, I would like to enable a firewall to ensure all connections go through the VPN. To this end, I have added this line to my OpenVPN configuration:

```
route-up /etc/openvpn/firewall-enable
```

Which points to a bash script with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
ufw enable
```

However, upon a system reboot, the VPN connection is made successfully, but `ufw status` reports that the firewall is still inactive.

Comment: Is the script executable?

Comment: Yes, the file is set to be executable for all users.